# Gitlab CI ERROR: Job failed

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a problem with Gitlab. I tried to add a new merge request - pipeline: failed, but everything looks fine and I am not sure why I get an error.

Job failed result:

```
Generating MSBuild file /builds/budgeting-app/budgetingapp.api/obj/budgetingapp.api.csproj.nuget.g.props.
Generating MSBuild file /builds/budgeting-app/budgetingapp.api/obj/budgetingapp.api.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
Generating MSBuild file /builds/budgeting-app/budgetingapp.api.tests/obj/budgetingapp.api.tests.csproj.nuget.g.props.
Generating MSBuild file /builds/budgeting-app/budgetingapp.api.tests/obj/budgetingapp.api.tests.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
Restore failed in 15.08 sec for /builds/budgeting-app/budgetingapp.api/budgetingapp.api.csproj.
Restore completed in 15.1 sec for /builds/budgeting-app/budgetingapp.api.tests/budgetingapp.api.tests.csproj.
Restoring packages for /builds/budgeting-app/budgetingapp.data/budgetingapp.data.csproj...
Restoring packages for /builds/budgeting-app/budgetingapp.data.tests/budgetingapp.data.tests.csproj...
Installing Microsoft.Build 15.3.409.
Installing Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core 15.3.409.
Installing Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core 15.3.409.
Installing Microsoft.Build.Framework 15.3.409.
Installing System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 4.0.1.
Installing Microsoft.Build.Runtime 15.3.409.
Restore completed in 1.78 sec for /builds/budgeting-app/budgetingapp.api/budgetingapp.api.csproj.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
  image : microsoft/dotnet:latest
stages:
   - test
before_script:
   - 'dotnet restore'
test:
  stage: test
  script:
     - 'cd budgetingapp.api.tests'
     - 'dotnet test'
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Job failed because your command returns nonzero exit code. Maybe it's because of:

```
Restore failed in 15.08 sec for /builds/budgeting-app/budgetingapp.api/budgetingapp.api.csproj.
```